# Accidentally deleted Kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a Kubernetes cluster on google cloud. I accidentally deleted a namespace which had a few pods running in it. Luckily, the pods are still running, but the namespace is in terminations state.

Is there a way to restore it back to active state? If not, what would the fate of my pods running in this namespace be?

Thanks

Comment: It's going to be hard... A namespace deletion may take some time but once it's finished, all resources inside of it is deleted, pod, services, secrets... I hope, for you, it wasn't in production.

Comment: Sadly it was. Is there I can backup and restore in a new namespace?

Comment: If you only have stateless app applying your conf again should do the trick... If some apps are statefull it will be another story if you don't have any disk snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

A few interesting articles about **backing up and restoring `Kubernetes cluster`** using various tools:

https://medium.com/@pmvk/kubernetes-backups-and-recovery-efc33180e89d

https://blog.kubernauts.io/backup-and-restore-of-kubernetes-applications-using-heptios-velero-with-restic-and-rook-ceph-as-2e8df15b1487

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-and-restore-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-digitalocean-using-heptio-ark

https://www.revolgy.com/blog/kubernetes-in-production-snapshotting-cluster-state

I guess they may be useful rather in future than in your current situation. If you don't have any backup, unfortunately there isn't much you can do.

Please notice that in all of those articles they use `namespace deletion` to **simulate disaster scenario** so you can imagine what are the consequences of such operation. However the results may not be seen immediately and you may see your pods running for some time but eventually **namespace deletion** *removes all kubernetes cluster resources in a given namespace* including `LoadBalancers` or `PersistentVolumes`. It may take some time. Some resource may not be deleted because it is still used by another resource (e.g. `PersistentVolume` by running `Pod`).

You can try and run [this](https://gist.github.com/negz/c3ee465b48306593f16c523a22015bec) script to dump all your resources that are still available to yaml files however some modification may be needed as you will not be able to list objects belonging to deleted namespace anymore. You may need to add `--all-namespaces` flag to list them.

You may also try to dump any resource which is still available manually. If you still can see some resources like `Pods`, `Deployments` etc. and you can run on them `kubectl get` you may try to save their definition to a yaml file:

```
kubectl get deployment nginx-deployment -o yaml > deployment_backup.yaml
```

Once you have your resources backed up you should be able to recreate your cluster more easily.

Comment: all backup all resources configuration: `kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o yaml > all-deploy-resources.yaml` reguarly

Answer (score 0):

backup most resource configuration reguarly:

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o yaml > all-deploy-resources.yaml
```

**but this is not includes all resources.**

another ways

by ark/velero:

https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero (Backup and migrate Kubernetes applications and their persistent volumes https://velero.io)