# Recover deleted namespace Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I run `kubectl delete` with `--all` flag. This command deleted all namespace on my cluster. (I couldn't see any namespace on K8S Dashboard) So How can I recover all these deleted namespace ?

And is it possible to restore data on namespance ?

```
➜ kubectl delete ns --all
warning: deleting cluster-scoped resources, not scoped to the provided namespace
namespace "1xx" deleted
namespace "2xx" deleted
namespace "3xx" deleted
namespace "4xx" deleted
namespace "5xx" deleted
namespace "6xx" deleted
namespace "7xx" deleted
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accidentally deleted Kubernetes namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375776/accidentally-deleted-kubernetes-namespace)

Comment: Actually I dont have any backup, so I think I have to restore from scatch

Comment: whatever the critical namespaces, such as `kube-system` are not deleted, maybe you can have a try, if all deployments are cicd automatically deployed.

Comment: To delete all namespaces, you don't specify a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your cluster is probably no longer viable and will need to be restored from backup or rebuilt.